# Shopping Mall Map Directory Editing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a shopping mall directory image (for example like this: http://www.westfield.com/annapolis/map/ ) and want to make an application like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNj8D8JKv-4&feature=related where I can draw the path between two locations without needing make many images for the paths.

So, What techniques (Library, programming techniques, softwares .. etc) do you suggest to do this using .NET (Windows Forms/ WPF) application?

### **EDIT for BOUNTY**

*I am looking for some start like. I am on 3rd Floor. I have a image of third floor. There is a point of entrance from 3rd floor in map. There are 29 seats in the floor. I want to show with line path, where is somebody's seat. I want to do it through **Web App. C# MVC 4.5** Where should I start from ? Any sample code will be very helpful.*

Answer (score 4):

I solved similar problem some time ago. In short, I was making a game like Heroes of Might and Magic and since I didn't want to draw background myself I decided to use a static image which I would simply manipulate along with player moves.

So we found an open-source game with a map editor that we used for creating of a map background. Then we created a mapper that would load an image created from the map editor and user would mark places on a grid. The following image is a screenshot from our map mapper.

[image]

There was the image, and drawed grid with adjustable size for cells so that we could map objects very precisely. The yellow boxes with an item inside are mapped objects (some of them actually do not give a sense, it is just a proof of concept). When we were content of the result, we would safe position and information about all obejcts to a xml file so that I can be used from our game application.

In our game we have defined a class called `TileMap` that was aware of all objects (stored as instances of a class `Tile`) on the map and all players move requests were permitted or forbidden by it.

**Finally**, this is how I would solve your problem. I have only positive experience with this solution. Create an application that would allow to you to specify where there is a path, where there is a store and how it is called, and so forth. Serialize values to xml or another format you are confident with. Then, create an application that works with these obejcts, define a tile map and you are nearly finished. Now you just need to implement path finding and drawing. Path finding is easy, there are plenty different algorithms with different efficiency and speed. Once you know what tiles you have to cross in order to get into a destination, simply draw stars, arrows or whatever you like above the tiles.

**Cons**

- you need to create two applications

**Pros**

- no need to generate more images, you are drawing on a transparent layer and you can safe already generated paths in memory or file
- quite easy implementation, just a lot of code
- feel free to choose a technology - we used WinRT, but WPF and even WinForms are also suitable
- if you like GUI applications, you will have a plenty of fun while doing this :)

Feel free to ask any design and even implementation details questions .

Comment: I am looking for some start like. I am on 3rd Floor. I have a image of third floor. There is a point of entrance from 3rd floor in map. There are 29 seats in the floor. I want to show with line path, where is somebody's seat. I want to do it through web app. MVC 4.5 Where should I start from ? Any sample code will be very helpful.

Comment: You can still create your personal mapper (WinForms, WPF) in order to get information about tiles and then if you want to do it in a web environment, I would use JS for drawing, C# for background things like path finding and so on. This app is so complex that it would take hundreds of lines of code to get you even started. I described the way for you, are you able to code it?

Comment: Any sample code will be highly appreciated for first comment...And Bounty will come to end.

Comment: @PKKG All right. I can provide whole map editor along with some key parts of the game. But then it will be up to you to take what you need from it and do the rest. I'll post it on github or somethink like that.

Comment: I will really appreciate in case you do something like highlighting somebody's seat with the with path starting from the floor entrance. I meant, I need, a route drawn using line from the entrance to the seat of the person need highlight.

Comment: You can't expect me to write the whole application for you. 500 reputation is fine, but it is not worthy even of a day of work - couple of hours at most. I will give you a working mapper so that you can generate a file, and the most important classes from the game so that you can load the file and use is somehow in your web application. I don't even work with JS so I couln't do the job for you even if I would be willing to.

Answer (score 3):

1. Prepare the list of all places that you want to be searchable. Give each one an ID. The stairs and elevators should have IDs too.
2. Create the map floor masks. The easy way is the "coloring book" technique. Create semi-transparent layer in Photoshop and overlay it above the map. Then, draw the walls with some set "color 1". Then, draw each distinct place with a distinct color. Just convert the place ID to Hex and use that hex value as the color. Draw the mask for each floor (in a separate image).
3. Create the map loader. It should load the mask images and extract the object position and passing ability information. You have to find the position (x, y, floor) of each place by scanning the maps and looking at the pixel color hex value. You have to locate the stairs and elevators, their positions and the floors that they connect.
4. Implement the [pathfinding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) like [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). It's quite easy and looks like viscous water flowing to the destination's low point. For each position (x, y, floor) one can move in any of the four directions where there aren't walls. And if there is an elevator at that point, one can move to some other floor. The algorithm can quickly find the best route between any two (x, y, floor) points.
5. When user gives you the name of the place where he wants to go, you need to find out the user's position coordinates (you may try to use GPS) and the destination position (use the object location table, you prepared when you loaded the map on step 3). Give these two (x, y, floor) points to the pathfinding algorithm to get back the route - the sequence of the (x, y, floor) points leading to the destination.
6. Analyze the route. You need to scan the route and find out what floors does it pass through. Split the route in chunks where each chunk belongs to a single floor. Now you have a list of floors and the route points for each of the floors.
7. Visualize the floors and their route parts by drawing the route points over the floor maps. To increase the root point spacing, you may just draw every 10th point or so. With HTML5, the sequence of route points can be drawn as an SVG or canvas overlay on top of the floor map image background.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set up something like this is to pick up a book on game programming, as it will give you a lot of information on setting up paths around "solid objects". The actual UI technology should not matter as much, so choose WPF or Windows Forms, HTML5 etc. Of the choices you have, I would probably aim for WPF or Silverlight, as it gives you much more flexibility on creating the UI. But I would not be adverse to HTML5 either.

Answer (score 0):

You can definately do the whole thing in WPF, you're looking at drawing simple paths so you need to chunk your project into multiple sub issues:

1) How to draw the UI area (i assume you already know that)

2) How to draw the map, it heavily depends on the map data you have but it could be as simple as a single image, please add more detail for your source

3) How to figure out the path, for this you will need to use some form of pathfinding algorithm (one of the simplest one is A*, but there is a myriad of algorithms for different needs)

4) How to draw the Path, this depends on what you're looking for once again

I know it isn't much of an answer yet but depending on your needs (please add a comment bellow) i'll edit it to help you the best i can.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty significant undertaking if you are trying to do this whole thing by yourself. All you have is image of shopping mall. From there you need to convert it in to vector data which in itself a fairly significant project. Then you will need to design navigation algorithms and then you need to setup UX for the whole thing. IMO, all these would require a lot of resources and research if you want to do this nicely and accurately.

Fortunately here is a good news: Google has been trying to do same thing for quite sometime and throwing lot more resources than that are likely at your disposal. Their effort is called "indoor mapping" which you can pretty much leverage out-of-box for your scenario. I'm going to give out here pointers to start you off as you have asked.

First visit [Google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-frontier-for-google-maps-mapping.html) to get familiarize with their indoor maps initiative. Then try out adding your floor plan in Google maps [here](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/floorplans/). You are basically uploading image and aligning with the building in Google maps at this point. Here's [another tutorial](http://sociable.co/technology/a-quick-guide-to-creating-a-google-maps-floor-plan/). Note that this does not make your floor plan navigable and may not show yet users location on it because to do that you need data from wifi/cell towers to triangulate users location on floor plan. We'll go over that next. If you have tons of these floor plans, I'd suggest taking help of mechanical turk or such service to have other humans do it for you cheaply. Google maps allows you to keep floor plan privates by using [overlays](http://coxydave.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-maps-image-overlay-tutorial.html) but likely you don't want to do that so users can access it from anywhere.

Next, you want to make your user locatable on your floor plan. This involves getting data such as wifi/cell tower signals at different points on your floor plan. Google has [app for this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.insight.surveyor&hl=en). And here's [little demo](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Maps-6.0-with-indoor-navigation-overview_id24224). You can also use SketchUp to add vector data and polygons.

Next, you want to embed Google maps in your app so it becomes integral part of your app  instead of users having to go through Google Maps website. To do this look at Maps SDK (here's [link for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/), and [snippet for indoor maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#indoor_maps)).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may easier this job by looking into Google map indoor solution. http://maps.google.com/help/maps/indoormaps/
No programming except a web page is needed.